# compatible types argument list types as the base version when method overriding?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

In book for scjp preparation I have read following:

```
Keep the following points in mind for correct overriding. The overriding method

 1. Should have the same argument list types (or compatible types) as
    the base version.

  ...
```

Can you provide example with  `compatible types` arguments ?

```
class Parent {
    public void m(Number n){}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void m(/*what can i write here?*/){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the definition [from JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)

### Overriding

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance
>   method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> C is a subclass of A.
>
> The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
>
> Either:
>
> m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same
>   package as C, or
>
> m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2),
>   such that m3 overrides m2.
>
> Moreover, if m1 is not abstract, then m1 is said to implement any and
>   all declarations of abstract methods that it overrides.

### What is subsignature?

> The signature of a method m1 is a **subsignature** of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>
> m2 has the same signature as m1, or
>
> the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature
>   of m2.
>
> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1
>   is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

### What are compatible types?

`Collection`  (raw type) and `Collection<String>`, because after type erasure they are same

Answer (score 1):

An example of "compatible types":

```
class C1 {
    public void m1 (List<Integer> l) {}
}

class C2 extends C1 {
    @Override
    public void m1 (List l) {}  // legal, this overrides
}
```

Basically, the only way a parameter list can have "compatible" types without having the exact same types is if the parameters of the overriding method are the same as the parameters of the overridden method with all type parameters removed.

The rule is explained in JLS §8.4.8.1 (SE8), which says that the signature of the overriding method must be a *subsignature* of the overridden one; following the references, we find that this means that "subsignature" means either it's the same signature or the type erasure of the overridden one.

(P.S. Of course, you shouldn't do this.  In real life, overriding methods should have the same parameter types, period.)

(PPS. Note that compatibility only goes one way here.  This is not legal:)

```
class C1 {
    public void m1 (List l) {}
}

class C2 extends C1 {
    @Override
    public void m1 (List<Integer> l) {}  // illegal
}
```

Comment: especially thanks for last clarification about one way